# How does this parameter knows the value of arr

Tags: javascript, parameters

How does the `elem` knows the value of `arr`

```js
function a(num){
  function ab(elem){
        let num=6
        return elem.length>num;
    }
    return ab;
  }

let arr=['caterpillar','justin','openhome'];
console.log(arr.filter(a()));
```

Comment: you meant to ask [how closure works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) or how to get `arr` as a parameter of `ab` ?

Comment: Because [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) passes them (values of `arr`) via `elem` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of executing the function `a` is function `ab`. This is being passed as the callback to `arr.filter`. `filter()` calls the provided callback function once for each element in the array. Hence function `ab` will receive the passed value in `elem`.

Apart from the current element being processed, `filter()` also passes index of the current element and the original array in this form
`callback( element , index, originalArray )`

To receive those values in function `ab` just add two more parameters like so

`ab(elem , index, arr)`

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)